# I want to have a word print alongside a textio that describes if the file is readable

Tags: python

The error it gives me is:

> expected type 'str', got 'bool' instead"

```
code:

stuff = open("stuff.txt", "r")

print("File readable = " + stuff.readable())
print(stuff.readlines())
stuff.close()
```

Comment: By the way, do yourself a favor and use a [context manager](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/context-manager-in-python/) to open and close files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert boolean to string:

```
print("File readable = " + str(stuff.readable()))
```

Or use [f-strings or formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings):

```
print(f"File readable = {stuff.readable()}")
```

Comment: Or simply give it as a second argument to `print()` instead of concatenating it: `print("File readable =", stuff.readable())`

Comment: Thanks! This helped alot.